# Help me find a counterexample in this measure theory problem

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f,f_n \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$  pointwise  and $ \displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}\int f_n=\int f}$ then there exists a $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}, \forall x\in\mathbb{R} \mid f_n(x)\mid \leq g(x)$

This is a true or false question. I think it's false but i can't find a counterexample. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Take $f_n=\frac n {\ln (n+1)} \chi_{(0,\frac 1 n)}, f=0$.

Comment: $f_n(x) = n{\bf 1}\{0< x < 1/n^2\}$

Comment: Let $f_n = \mathbf{1}_{\left [n, n+\frac{1}{n} \right]}$ and  $f=0$.